# Notification Service extension doesn't run on app install

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, usernotifications, unnotificationserviceextension

I have successfully implemented push notifications for my app. I have also activated Notification service extension to suit my needs. The problem arises when I uninstall the app and run the app from Xcode again the service extension doesn't work. It only works if I explicitly run it from Xcode to make it work. How can I make it work by just installing the app without having to run the extension from Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to run it once with your main target then change the target to service extension re run again